# How can I manipulate text in bash?

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

How can I manipulate text in bash using either awk, grep, perl or sed?

Input:

```
ted foo,bar,zoo
john ket,ben
```

Expected Output:

```
foo,ted
bar,ted
zoo,ted
ket,john
ben,john
```

Comment: Please add your coding efforts to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ ,]"; OFS=","} {for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $i,$1}' file
```

Output:

```
foo,ted
bar,ted
zoo,ted
ket,john
ben,john
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – **FS**, **OFS**, RS, ORS, NR, **NF**, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)